# Find the store type which sells the maximum products in terms of sales amount & by quantity sold ? <SQL Server>

Tags: sql, sql-server

For this question, I have a table named as 'Transactions' and the variables of this table are as follows :

- total_amt : It contains amount paid by customer when a transaction took place.
- Qty : It contains quantities ordered by customer of a particular product.
- prod_subcat_id : It contains products' subcategories ID
- prod_cat_id : It contains the products' category ID.
- store_type : It contains store type. It has 4 values - Flagship Stores, 
             Online, e-store, debcred

Since the question demands that store type should sell maximum products by value of sales amount & by value of quantities sold. So it might be a case where sales amount is max for a store type (lets say Store_A) but value of quantities sold is max for some other store type (lets say Store_B)
But this is not the case with the given data. so whichever store_type holds the max Value of sales_Amt also holds the max value of quantities sold.

Below is the query I have written so far. But it surely has some problem with alias names or something in the inline view or in the subquery. Also I have to achieve the output using subqueries in having clause.

```
select 
    store_type,
    sum(cast(total_amt as float)),
    sum(cast(Qty as int))
from Transactions
group by Store_type
having 
    sum(cast(total_amt as float)) = 
    (
        select MAX(cast(total_amt as float))
        from(
            select SUM(cast(total_amt as float)) as col1 
            from Transactions
            group by Store_type
        )
    ) as T1 AND 
    sum(cast(Qty as int)) = 
    (
        select MAX(cast(Qty as int))
        from(
            select SUM(cast(Qty as int)) as col2
            from Transactions
            group by Store_type
        ) as T2
```

Comment: Thanks....I was able to figure out the mistake in my code & fixed it on my own.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use query below, of course if i am not mistaken

```
;WITH a AS(
SELECT t.store_type,SUM(cast(t.total_amt as float)) amountSum,SUM(cast(t.Qty as Int)) totalCount 
FROM Transactions AS t
GROUP BY t.store_type
)
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM a AS a
ORDER BY a.amountSum desc,a.totalCount desc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use an `order by` clause and pick the top 1

```
select top 1 store_type,
sum(cast(total_amt as float)) as sales_amt,
sum(cast(Qty as int)) as qty_sold
from Transactions
group by Store_type
order by sales_amt desc,qty_sold desc
```

Comment: I have also tried this and it gave me the output but logically it is incorrect because when We would use order by...It will only work for the first column that We would have mentioned and i.e., sales_amt column in this case. Since both max sales_amt & max qty sold are achieved by the same store.So orderby would work. 
But I would like my query to be more advanced so that If max value of sales_amt is achieved by storeA & max value of qty_sold achieved by storeA. In this case subquery approach will return blank output.
But If We use order by..It will display some result which is incorrect.